# Idle timeout in a react redux application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, redux

I am trying to create an idle timeout feature in a react-redux application where after a certain time, (lets say 30 mins) the user gets logged out due to inactivity.  I have looked around SO and found some examples with react only, however, what if redux is in the mix of the application?

I am going to use react-idle-timer but I want to be able to use that in all of my routes so maybe creating a high order component?  Anyone with experience building this that can point me in the right direction?

Comment: redux itself doesn't support it by design - of course hoc can be done with throttled dispatching

Comment: @xadm redux-sage huh, cant say i have used that before, would that be an overkill for this task in your experience?